# AngularJS - Changing a template depending to a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am fairly new to Angular and I find it quite difficult to think the Angular way.

I have registered a SessionService which loads a user object at login. Each controller can depend on the SessionService so I can have some sort of access control.

```
app.factory('SessionService',['$resource', function($resource){

    var service = $resource('/session/:param',{},{
      'login': {
        method: 'POST'
      }
    });

    var _user = { authorized: false };

    function getUser() {
      return _user;
    }

    function authorized(){
      return _user.authorized === true;
    }

    function unauthorized(){
      return _user.authorized === false;
    }

    function login(newUser,resultHandler) {
      service.login(
        newUser,
        function(res){
          _user = (res.user || {});
          _user.authorized = res.authorized;
          if(angular.isFunction(resultHandler)) {
            resultHandler(res);
          }
        }
      );
    }
    return {
      login: login,
      authorized: authorized,
      getUser: getUser
    };
  }]);
```

...this is how I access the SessionService from a controller:

```
app.controller('SidebarCtrl', ['$scope', 'SessionService', function($scope, SessionService) {
  $scope.template = '/templates/sidebar/public.html';
  if(SessionService.authorized()){
      $scope.template = '/templates/sidebar/menu.html';  // <-- ???
  }
}]);
```

...and here the html file:

```
<div ng-controller="SidebarCtrl">
  <div ng-include src="template"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my question: **How do I make the SidebarCtrl's template dependent on SessionService.authorize?** So the sidebar shows the right content according to a user being logged in or not.

I hope this makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `$watch` the `SessionService.authorized()`. So change the controller as:

```
app.controller('SidebarCtrl', ['$scope', 'SessionService', function($scope, SessionService) {
    $scope.template = null;
    $scope.$watch(
        function() {
            return SessionService.authorized();
        },
        function(authorized) {
            if( authorized ) $scope.template = '/templates/sidebar/menu.html';
            else $scope.template = '/templates/sidebar/public.html';
        }
    );
}]);
```

Comment: Fast and precise! Thank you very much. I wonder why I can't find $watch in the API documentation...

Comment: @sven if you dont know $watch, i recommend you look to angular offic tutorial (https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning/blob/master/README.md) and best Egghead.io for more tips and skills

Comment: It's in the docs for [Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope). Getting acquianted with the doc format of a new system is always a pain!